# Migration embedded linux to larger sd

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, migration

Im trying to migrate an embedded system, im ussing the dd comand

`dd if=/dev/location of=/dev/destiny`

but as said on the main title im trying to migrate to a larger sd, first I want to be sure that the OS can launch, but it only stays on a dark screen, is there something that Im missing???

is a 4Gb to a 8Gb, im using Linux Mint 14.1 (Nadia) cinnamon 64 bits .

And the OS I want to migrate is ubuntu-10.04 Lucid.

Comment: Have you tried using [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) as opposed to just low-level copying the bytes with `dd`?  It would also facilitate resizing the partition to fill the SD card entirely.  Also, [this guide](http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions) regarding RPi flash partition resizing *may* be worth glancing through.

Comment: First I want to be sure that the OS is copied correctly, but it doesn't launch, I want to knwo why, and then resize the memory it can use. It's quite a useful guide though... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Better create the filesystems you want on the target, and copy the files. This will help by not copying stuff that isn't needed, and should also lay out the files sequentially on the target, even if they are fragmented on the source.

Comment: the problem is that I need the system the way it is, I don't know if they have something special in it but I need to migrate it the way it is, that's why I need it like that. But as a last resource I'll do it like you just said. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Copying the files recursively (with a little care on "hidden" files in the root of a filesystem) should give you an exact replica...

Comment: It does... but it doesn't run... it shows the same folders and files that are on the original SD card.

Comment: since time is over me, do you know a guide to install an embedded OS but choosing some packages???, some of the packages it has I don't really need them.